# Create a range of quarters from year to year in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I wish to create a list of all the quarters from a given range of years, say from 2018 to 2020, ie.: `[2018-q1, 2018-q2, ..., 2020-q4]`.

How could I achieve that in Pandas?

This code may be useful: `pd.PeriodIndex(df.date, freq='Q')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `pd.PeriodIndex()`+`pd.date_range()`:

```
out = pd.PeriodIndex(pd.date_range('2018-01-01','2021-01-01',freq = 'Q'), freq = 'Q')
print(out)
```

Out:

```
PeriodIndex(['2018Q1', '2018Q2', '2018Q3', '2018Q4', '2019Q1', '2019Q2',
             '2019Q3', '2019Q4', '2020Q1', '2020Q2', '2020Q3', '2020Q4'],
            dtype='period[Q-DEC]')
```

OR

`pd.date_range()`+`to_period()`:

```
out = pd.date_range('2018-01-01', '2021-01-01', freq = 'Q').to_period('Q')
print(out)
```

Out:

```
PeriodIndex(['2018Q1', '2018Q2', '2018Q3', '2018Q4', '2019Q1', '2019Q2',
             '2019Q3', '2019Q4', '2020Q1', '2020Q2', '2020Q3', '2020Q4'],
            dtype='period[Q-DEC]')
```

Comment: The option #2 is slightly faster

Answer (score 1):

Glad to answer on your question.

```
idx = pd.Series(pd.period_range(start="2018-Q1", end="2020-Q4", freq="Q")).array
print(idx)
```

Out:

```
['2018Q1', '2018Q2', '2018Q3', '2018Q4', '2019Q1', '2019Q2', '2019Q3',
 '2019Q4', '2020Q1', '2020Q2', '2020Q3', '2020Q4']
Length: 12, dtype: period[Q-DEC]
```

Hope to be helpful for you. Thanks.